# Set fixed width to image with ImageMagic library

Tags: imagemagick, gm

I'm trying to generate following image:
[image]

this is my code. I'm using out command to set fix with to font:

```js
    const gm = require("gm").subClass({ imageMagick: true });
    gm(1800, 2400, "transparent")
      .fill("#ffffff")
      .drawRectangle(400, 400, 1400, 1400)
      .font("ananda.ttf", 90)
      .background("transparent")
      .out(
        "-size",
        "1600",
        "-gravity",
        "center",
        "caption: very very very long text very very very long text long long",
        "-geometry",
        "+0+400",
        "-composite"
      )
    
      .write("drawing.png", function (err) {
        if (err) return console.dir(arguments);
        console.log(this.outname + " created  :: " + arguments[3]);
      });
```

but when I'm trying to add `.composite(foregroundImagePath)` before or after out, it's not working.

`'0': Error: Command failed: composite: unrecognized option`-fill' @ error/composite.c/CompositeImageCommand/1021.`

1. is there better way to rather use `out` command?
2. how to add final picture to the image?

Comment: Composite requires 2 input images and an output image. I only see you creating the text image. So there is no second image for the composite until you provide your art image.  Sorry, I do not know gm, only Imagemagick command line.

Comment: gm works perfectly with single argument. 

```const backgroundImagePath = "canvas.png";
const foregroundImagePath = "image.png";

gm(backgroundImagePath)
  .composite(foregroundImagePath)
  .write("final.png", function (err) {
    if (err) return console.dir(arguments);
    console.log(this.outname + " created  :: " + arguments[3]);
  });``` 

but any maybe any hints how to do this only with out command?

Comment: Post your input art image and your font file. I can only show you in Imagemagick command line, not gm.